# How to write a SQL query such that the return is keyed to multiple inputs?

Tags: sql, database

I have an array of 40,000 'rough' entity names and need to match these to 'clean' names as they appear in a database of 500,000 entities. Using the rough names to match on, (see python part below), I am getting 3 or 4 possible 'clean name' return values for each rough name supplied. Later code chooses the best match.

A simple loop over the rough names is fine for 10 names but I do not want to loop through all 40,000 rough names doing individual database calls! So is there a SQL query I can write where I pass all of the rough names in one go but ensure the returned matches are still keyed to each rough input name for further analysis?

Just looping over the first 10 rough names I am doing the following:

In python:

```
for index, row in rough_names_array.iterrows():
    rough_string = str(row["rough_name"])
    SQL_query = ("SELECT clean_name FROM big_db WHERE clean_name LIKE '%" + rough_string + "%' ")
    query = big_db(SQL_query) //example code to make the DB call
    clean_name_options = np.array(query["clean_name"])
```

My current SQL query:

```
SELECT clean_name 
FROM big_db 
WHERE clean_name LIKE '%" + rough_string + "%'
```

Comment: This will be quite time-consuming in the  database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to make this efficient using a single query. I would create a (possibly temporary) table to store rough names, bulk-insert your array into it, and then retrieve all the results by joining `big_db` to that table.

UPD: Assuming you make a table called `rough_names` with a single column `rough_name` and fill it out, the query would look like this:

```
SELECT r.rough_name, b.clean_name
FROM big_db b
INNER JOIN rough_names r
ON b.clean_name LIKE '%'||r.rough_name||'%'
```

Note that this will not work on MS SQL server since it doesn't support `||` for string concatenation; use `+` instead if that's the case.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am very new to SQL, would you be able to give an example of the code you would use to do the join?